# What is the weight tag on the CALCULATION LINKBASE of a XBRL Report

Tags: xml, xbrl

I'm sorry if this question is out of 
What is the weight tag on the CALCULATION LINKBASE of an XBRL Report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weight attribute is multiplied by the value when calculating a total.  You will generally only see values of "1", indicating that facts for that concept should be added, and "-1" indicating that facts for that concept should be subtracted.

So if you have a calculation of Income = Revenue - Costs,  Revenue would have a weight of +1 and Costs would have -1

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to pdw's answer: the weight attribute also has another role in terms of validation and consistency.

Errors will be returned if concepts marked with a credit balance are "added" (both positive weights) to concepts marked as debit, or subtracted to concepts marked as credit.

In the example above of `Income = Revenue - Costs`, this calculation is valid if Income and Revenue have a credit balance, and Costs has a debit balance.